# Android How to pass image MultiPart form data through webView.evaluateJavascript()

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, webview

I am developing an application in which I need to send image from android native Activity to a attached webView java script function below is my code to send data from android to a webView JS function.

```
mWebView.evaluateJavascript("showImage(${mFile});", null)
```

If I send any data like string or integer and print it on html it works, but when I send a Multipart object and try to view image or print details then nothing happened on WebView.

Is this possible to send multipart via evaluateJavascript() function? if yes then please help,
Thank You!